# std::dec still outputting memory address to hex?

Tags: c++

I have:

```
std::cout << "Start = " << std::dec << (&myObject) << std::endl;
```

to output an address in decimal. However, the address is still coming out in hex??

(I am outputting one of these for each of ten members, so I don't want to assign each one to a variable and then `std::dec` the variable separately)

Comment: std::cout << "Start = " << uint32_t((&myObject)) << std::endl;
that work? x86?

Comment: @hanshenrik: Why make assumptions about pointer type sizes when `uintptr_t` was created precisely for this purpose???

Comment: i can't think of any reasons :D i just didn't know about the intptr_t when i wrote it; thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `hex` and `dec` manipulators are for *integers*, not pointers. Pointers are *always* rendered in the form that `printf`'s `%p` formatter would have used on your system (which is, usually, hexadecimal notation).

This helps to emphasise the fact that pointers and numbers are distinct. You may consider it to be one of the rare cases in which number semantics and number representation are, to some degree, coupled.

The best you can do is to cast the pointer to `uintptr_t` before streaming it:

```
std::cout << "Start = " << std::dec << uintptr_t(&myObject) << std::endl;
```

…but please consider whether you *really* need to do so.

Comment: Why the "whether you really need to do so"?

Comment: @user997112: I explained that in the rest of the answer. What makes you think you need to represent pointers in an unconventional manner? That's usually not a good idea.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  `std::dec` is superfluous in this case

Comment: @vsoftco: You don't know what state the stream is in from previous operations.