# How to print addresses (Hex values) in upper case in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print the address(reference) of a variable in hex and that too in upper case. But I see that I'm able to print the hex equivalent of 77 in upper case, but not the address(reference) of a variable. Can somebody help me please?

The following is the program I have the difficulty with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void print_nb_of_items(const int nb_of_apple, const int& nb_of_pens)
{
    cout << "Number of apples = " << nb_of_apple << endl;
    cout << "Number of pens = " << nb_of_pens << " Address = " << uppercase << hex << &nb_of_pens << endl;
    cout << "Hex output in uppercase = " << uppercase << hex << 77 << endl;
}

/* The main function */

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int nb_apple = 24;
    int nb_pens = 65;
    print_nb_of_items(nb_apple, nb_pens);

    return 0;
}
```

The output for the program I got is:

```
Number of apples = 24
Number of pens = 65 Address = 0xbffbd438
Hex output in uppercase = 4D
```

I want the address to be printed as: 0xBFFBD438.
How do I do that?

Comment: Works fine for me. What compiler do you use?

Comment: cast to `uintptr_t`? Output of pointers is hex only "by convention", not defined by the standard. If you have a C++ compiler for, say, PDP-11, it may well output addresses in octal, as that is the general standard output format for pointers in that architecture.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Doesn't for me here: http://ideone.com/K1Dwy1

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Well, I've never really gotten into all the stream manipulators. A quick workaround could be to read the value into a stringstream and convert the resulting string to uppercase (always keeping in mind that the hex representation itself is platform-specific).

Comment: @ChristianHackl As Mats mentioned implementation of output for `void*` is not clearly defined.

Comment: What is this "address (reference)" terminology you've employed? References and pointers are different things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *"I want the address to be printed as: 0xBFFBD438. How do I do that?"*

Well, [@MatsPetterson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919155/mats-petersson) hit the nail on the head in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795137/how-to-print-addresses-hex-values-in-upper-case-in-c/28795268?noredirect=1#comment45864837_28795137), casting the address value to a `uintptr_t`

```
cout << "Number of pens = " << nb_of_pens 
     << " Address = 0x" << uppercase << hex 
     << uintptr_t(&nb_of_pens) << endl;
     // ^^^^^^^^^^           ^
```

just makes it work fine (see fully working sample [here](http://ideone.com/YW4LKQ) please).

---

To explain in more depth:
The implementation of

```
 std::ostream operator<<(ostream& os, void* ptr);
```

isn't further specified by the standard, and may simply not be affected by/considering the `std::uppercase` I/O manipulator. Conversion of the pointer value to a plain number, will take the `std::uppercase` and `std::hex` I/O manipulators into effect.

Comment: Why not `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: I once had [this silly discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout/19562163#19562163) already. I prefer shortness for formatting purposes.

Comment: Not to mention that C-style casts don't get incorrectly written as reinterpret_cats ... :)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Isn't `reinterpret_cast` the only of the C++-style casts which works here?

Comment: @ChristianHackl  Yes. But well, as mentioned for readability and purpose it looks just overkill for me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I realise that. I was just wondering, after reading Mats' comment, if there was more to this than readability.

Comment: None of the other C++ style casts will work, but compiler will do the right thing with a C-style cast (the problem with C-style casts is generally that they WILL do `reinterpret_cast` when that's not quite what you wanted - and of course, the ability to search for `_cast` is much better than to try to search for `(random_type)`)

Answer (score 3):

Like `printf("%p", &obj)`, the stream output format of a pointer is entirely unspecified. By convention we get a hexadecimal value and, on some systems, that abides by `std::uppercase` (and friends). [But you cannot rely on that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28661888/560648). Those I/O manipulators are there for *numbers*, not *pointers*.

You can actually transform your pointer into a number to guarantee the behaviour you want:

```
cout << "Number of pens = " << nb_of_pens
     << " Address = " << uppercase << hex << uintptr_t(&nb_of_pens)
     << endl;
```

Comment: Your link really adds some more useful information.